# Patterns in module

Tags: pattern-matching, scoping

I have this weird behavior of patterns inside the `Module` construct. Note that we have

```
In: Module[{}, a_->x]
Out: a_ -> x
```

While if `x` is scoped, then some garbage also appears in `a`

```
In: Module[{x}, a_->x]
Out: a$_ -> x$16509
```

Even more, it doesn't help if `x` has a value,

```
In: Module[{x}, x=4; a_->x]
Out: a$_ -> 4
```

Is there any explanation for this behavior/can it be avoided in some straightforward way? Note that this does not happen in `Block`.

The reason this is problematic for me is because I receive a global expression with variable `a`, and I want it to appear in the right hand side of the pattern, i.e.

```
In: expr=a^2; Module[{x}, x=4; stuff[a_]->expr * x]
Out: stuff[a$_] -> 4 a^2
```

P.S. Mathematica 11.2.0.0

Comment: Linked topic should answer you doubts and provide broader context. Let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks! I didn't realize this is such a general thing..